# Error in rosmake bumblebee2 under fuerte

Tags: ros, bumblebee2, camera-info-manager

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I met a problem to install bumblebee2 package in ROS.
In the fist try, the error is:

fatal error: camera_info_manager/camera_info.h: No such file or directory

Then, I follow the suggestion by Pulkit to replace camera_info.h to camera_info_manager.h.

The old problem is solved, but there is a new issue. The definition of "CameraInfoManager *cinfo_;" is wrong. Pulkit suggested that "Replace the places where the variable cinfo_ is declared/initialized to camera_info_manager::cinfo_h". I am not quite sure what this mean as cinfo_h is not the member of camera_info_manager. Does anyone know how to solve this issue?

Thank you and Happy new year to all the ROSers.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/51218/error-in-rosmake-bumblebee2-under-fuerte/) by [Huang](https://answers.ros.org/users/3864/huang/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2012-12-29

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The bumblebeer2 driver is not actively maintained. You can look at the [camera1394](http://ros.org/wiki/camera1394) driver, from which it is derived, to determine what updates are needed to make it work with current ROS releases.

Or, you can update your question to include the code that is failing, so we can help you figure out what is wrong.

---

Originally posted by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) with karma: 25443 on 2013-01-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1